# UI поток и большой объем информации

Tags: android, многопоточность

Есть TableLayout, заполняется большим количеством данных. Из-за выполнения в главном потоке (в другом потоке ведь нельзя) интерфейс подвисает на время заполнения таблицы. Есть ли варианты решения такой проблемы?
Как работают крупные приложения, обновляя UI без зависаний потока?

Comment: Возможно, у вас не всё содержимое таблицы видно на экране и вы его в ScrollView оборачиваете. Коли так, то замените на RecyclerView всё это. Так будет отрисовываться только то, что отображается в данный момент на экране.

Comment: Да, это в ScrollView, но таблица на весь экран, она по-любому должна будет прорисовываться полностью. Да и создавать еще больше элементов для RecyclerView выйдет расточительнее, наверно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableLayot`, как и `GridLayout` и `ListLayout` - штуки очень, скажем так, примитивные и считаются устаревшими. При большом количестве объектов они сильно тупят и жрут неимоверное количество оперативной памяти. Им на замену пришел `RecyclerView`. Он снимает с вас задачу по непосредственному наполнению, вы только описываете элементы, и он создает не все элементы сразу, а только видимые, что сильно ускоряет работу приложения и снижает расход памяти. О том как это работаем можно говорить долго, но если количество элементов(строк таблицы) хотя бы вдвое превышает число умещающихся одновременно на экране, то в `RecyclerView` будет эффективнее. Если нет - он будет как минимум не медленнее/прожорливее простого `TableLayout`

Итого, вам однозначно стоит переходить на `ReceyclerView` или на аналогичный элемент для таблиц, вроде [такого](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) или [такого](https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders). Переиспользование View в списках, число элементов которых неизвестно или велико, сегодня вещь обязательная